# Extract email domain using Python regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, newline, whitespace

I'm trying to extract the domain name from email addresses using

```
 domain = re.search('(@^\S$)', email)
```

I want to match any non-whitespace character excluding newline. However, my variable is not returning anything Please advise on my though process below:

- **(@** means we are starting the string after or at the @ symbol
- **^\S** indicates to repeat any non-whitespace characters after @
- **$)** means to exclude /n or newline and end there

Comment: Your *any non-whitespace character excluding newline* sounds strange. A non-whitespace char does not match a newline. Do you mean you want `re.search(r'(?m)@\S+$', email)`? Or do you want to extract multiple occurrences from the end of all lines - `re.findall(r'(?m)@(\S+)$', email)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex matches `@` followed by the beginning of the line followed by a single non-whitespace character followed by the end of the input. (I’m assuming that you’ve properly escaped the backslash for a string in your actual code.)

What you want to do is match the position *after* `@` then any number of non-whitespace characters, then the end of the input:

```
domain = re.search(r"(?<=@)(\S+$)", email)
```

Here, `(?<=@)` is a lookbehind, which tests that the previous character or characters match the contents of the parentheses; `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters; and `$` matches the end of the line.

Another option, which doesn’t require regexes, is:

```
domain = email.split("@")[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` metacharacter matches the start of the string, so putting it anywhere but at the start of the pattern will never match anything.

Also, `\S` will match unwanted characters, instead we can have a look at the [specifications for domain name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain) to match exactly what is needed.

Finally, you can use a capturing group to capture the domain and throw away the `@`.

```
import re

email = 'foo@stackoverflow.com'

domain = re.search('@((\w|\w[\w\-]*?\w)\.\w+)', email).group(1)

print(domain) # stackoverflow.com
```